# Uniqueness of a Least Square system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, least-squares

I set up the least squares  system to find coefficients $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)$ for fitting the model function $$f(t) = x_1t + x_2e^t$$
to the three data points $(1,2), (2,3), (3,5).$
I want to know if the system have a unique solution.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(1) = & x_1 t + x_2 e  = 2\\
f(2) = & 2x_1 t + x_2 e^2 = 3\\
f(3) = & 3x_1 t + x_2 e^3 = 5 \\
\end{split}  
\quad \equiv \quad
\begin{split} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 + x_2e\\ 
2x_1 + x_2e^2 \\ 
3x_1 + x_2e^3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\3\\5 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{split}
\ \equiv \ 
\begin{split} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e\\ 
2 & e^2 \\ 
3 & e^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\3\\5 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since minimizing the least squares is equivalent to solving the normal equation, I use it to solve for the solution
$$\min\limits_{\vec{x}}\|Ax - b\|_2 \equiv A^\top A \vec{x} = A^\top b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
e & e^2 & e^3\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e\\ 
2 & e^2 \\ 
3 & e^3
\end{bmatrix}
\vec{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
e & e^2 & e^3\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\3\\5 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$ \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
14 & e + 2^e + 3e^3\\ 
e + 2^e + 3e^3 & e^2 + e^4 + e^6\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \times 
\begin{bmatrix}
23\\2e + 3e^2 + 5e^3 
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1.5942\\0.0088
 \end{bmatrix}$$

So in order to know if $\vec{x}$ is unique I reduced $A^{m\times n}$ into reduced row echelon form to find the linearly independent rows/columns:
RREF$(A) = \text{RREF}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e\\ 
2 & e^2 \\ 
3 & e^3
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$

Rank(A) = $\min(m,n) = 2 \implies A$ is full rank $\implies \vec{x}$ is unique.

I am not sure whether my conclusion about the uniqueness of $\vec{x}$ is true since $m>n$. What I know is that assuming $m\le n$ then my conclusion would have been true but this is the case where $m>n.$ Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Since $A$ has full rank and $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^TA)$ we know $A^TA\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is invertible so $$A^TAx=A^Tb \iff x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$ and $x$ is unique.

Comment: I thought about that but weren't sure of the case $m>n$

Comment: Is your $m$ equal to the number of rows and $n$ the number of columns? If $A$ is $m\times n$ with $m>n$ and $A$ has full rank, then its rank must be $n$ making $A^TA$ invertible.

Comment: On the other hand if $n>m$ and the columna of $A$ span all of $\mathbb{R}^m$ then the rank of $A$ is $m$ so $A^TA$ wouldn't be inverible. This would imply $A^TAx=A^Tb$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yeah. You're right.